# mime error when linking css file / css styling doesnt work

Tags: css, node.js, express

So I have the css link here:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/html" href="/public/assets/lib/css/style.css" />
```

Now, in this current state the styling doesn't show up at all. I've looked into what others have said and tried:

- take off rel="stylesheet"
- change to "text/html"
- check the paths
- put it in public folder regards to express
- add `<base href="/">`
- etc..

still I'm having issues.

If I have text/css, I get mime errors.

my file path below:

[image: file path]

app.js:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var request = require("request");
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("search");
  // res.render("location");
```

header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
```

> *

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/html" href="/public/assets/lib/css/style.css" />
```

> *

```
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:600|Open+Sans&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3870ba704e.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <title>tv guide</title>
  </head>
  <body>
```

search:

```
<%- include('partials/header') %>
<section class="container-fluid content">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <i class="fas fa-tape">filmraid</i>
    </a>
  </nav>

  <h1>Search for a Movie</h1>

  <form action="results" method="GET">
    <input type="text" placeholder="search term" name="search" />
    <!-- <br />
  <input type="radio" id="usMovies" name="location" /> US
  <input type="radio" id="ukMovies" name="location" /> UK -->
    <br />
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
</section>
<%- include('partials/footer') %>
```

I'm wondering if I'm missing something else here.
Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: You are using `type="text/html"` on a css file.. use `text/css` instead.

Comment: @SaurabhSharma like noted above the text/css causes mime error

Comment: Change `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` to `app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'public'));` and change `href="/public/assets/lib/css/style.css"`  to `href="/assets/lib/css/style.css"`

Comment: @SaurabhSharma the styles still don't apply not sure why. I had this originally  also.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem by:

- creating a new public folder since

http://localhost:3000/assets/lib/css/styles.css

was unreachable.